# How to find the duration of .swf file using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am embedding a .swf file in web page and I want to raise an event when .swf file has finished playing. After searching Google I came to know that it is not possible directly in JavaScript. But I assume that calculating the duration of .swf file and setting the timer according to the time may give me approximate result.
But I am not aware of any api available for this. Could you please tell me if any api is available and suggest me if any better alternative solution is available to achieve the same.

Comment: .swf timelines count frames, not seconds, and user interaction can affect now long it actually runs in any number of ways. You're asking for a datum that doesn't actually exist.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any control over the swf code?  If so, ExternalInterface can help you with this.  Otherwise, I don't believe you can grab duration from swf files, as they're not a linear-specific format.

Comment: in the good old days you could do this via the flashobj.frame property but you cannot access the swf inner workings since flash player 8 came in